# Obtaining "this" tab ID from content script in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

From a content script, is it possible to access that tab's `id`?

I want to send a message to the background page from the content script that tells my extension to "do something with this tab" using the `chrome.tabs.*` API.

A `tabID` is needed, and there is no point in doing a bunch of logic in the background page to hunt for a `tabID` when my content script can simply tell it the `tabID` in the message contents.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Tab id is automatically passed inside [MessageSender](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#type-MessageSender) object:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("sent from tab.id=", sender.tab.id);
});
```

Note: According to [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#type-MessageSender), this property is not always available:

> This property will **only** be present when the connection was opened from a tab (including content scripts), and only if the receiver is an extension, not an app.

Comment: Thanks... I completely overlooked the sender parameter. I thought I had to do this.tabId or something inside of my content script.

Comment: For posterity: unfortunately the tabIds reported in chrome.WebRequest response details objects are consistently -1 for requests initiated from background pages (as of the time of this comment).

Comment: @serg: What if I need tabID outside message response processor?

Comment: I get following: Uncaught Error: sendRequest and onRequest are obsolete. Please use sendMessage and onMessage instead

Comment: @c00000fd: See my answer below.

Comment: Hmm... for me sender is my extension's page, not the activepage

Comment: I was not able to get `sender.tab`. After reading the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#type-MessageSender) I realized that it was because I was sending the message from popup.

Answer (score 43):

If you want the `tabId` of yourself (in my case in Content Script) without requiring "`tabs`" permission, a workaround is to have Content Script send a dummy message to the background script, then have background script respond with `sender.tab.id` back to the Content Script!

e.g. in `content.js`:

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ text: "what is my tab_id?" }, tabId => {
   console.log('My tabId is', tabId);
});
```

and in `background.js`:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.text == "what is my tab_id?") {
        sendResponse({tab: sender.tab.id});
     }
});
```

it's a stupid workaround that worked for me. :)

PS. Oh, if you have `tabs` permission then you can run this async query very easily:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    var myTabId = tabs[0].id;
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(myTabId, {text: "hi"}, function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: "sendResponse() will be removed from the W3C spec. The popular webextension-polyfill library has already removed the sendResponse() function", says [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage)

Comment: @KongKao I haven't being able to use `sendResponse()` successfully in Firefox, but also can't find that text in your link where it says that `sendResponse()` will be removed

Comment: chrome.tabs.query cannot be used from within a content script. It is only available in background and popup scripts.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Ports for two-way long-lived connections, the second argument in the callback is a Port object, so to access the tab ID is then:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
  if (port.name === "foo") {
    port.onMessage.addListener((msg, sendingPort) => {
      console.log("sent from tab.id=", sendingPort.sender.tab.id);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: "sendingPort.sender.tab.id" was just what I was missing, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If a content script is injected programmatically,
another approach is to store `tabId` in a global variable:

```js
const injectTabId = (callback) => chrome.tabs.executeScript(
  tabId,
  {code: `window.tabId = ${tabId}`},
  callback
);

const injectFile = () => chrome.tabs.executeScript(
  tabId,
  {file: 'content.js'}
);

injectTabId(injectFile);
```

In the content script, access it with `window.tabId`. The variable
won't be exposed to page scripts because of content scripts
living in an isolated world.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `manifest_version: 3` and a content script is injected programmatically, another approach is to store `tabId` in a global variable:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tabId },
      args: [tabId],
      func: (id) => {
        window.tabId = id;
      }
    });
    await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tabId },
      files: ['content.js']
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction of the selected answer for nowadays:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("sent from tab.id=", sender.id);
});
```

Comment: according to [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#type-MessageSender), `sender.id` returns the id of the extension/app, not the id