# update popup.html content dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup, google-chrome-devtools

I am sending a message from the **contentscript** to **popup** and trying to show  the received message when the extension is clicked.

[image]

I can see that the message is being received only when I **Inspect popup**
 [image]

**contentscript.js**

```
    console.log("content script");      

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("hello",function(response)
    {
        console.log("sending message");        
    });
```

**popup.js**

```
console.log("popup script");   

function onReq(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
  ph=request;
    console.log("msg: "+request);
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "msg: "+request;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onReq);
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <p id="para">shows received message here</p>
  </body>
   <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

I want to receive the message and show the message when clicked without having to open the console.
How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The popup window is created/destroyed each time you open/close the popup. So sending messages to it while closed will not work. A simple solution would be to store the latest message in [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), and read the value from the popup.

Comment: Everytime I open a new tab and run the extension, the previous value is still shown.
How can i create different instances of the storage such that each tab has its own storage space.

Comment: @Vinay The storage is shared across the entire extension. So you will need to store the messages in an object, where each message is indexed by the tab ID. The `chrome.tabs` API may be of help.

Comment: see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202953/obtaining-this-tab-id-from-content-script-in-chrome-extension